# ggplot - Labeling each line at the end using an arrow

Tags: r, ggplot2

The question probably sounds confusing, so here are a couple of pictures to illustrate what I am trying to achieve.

Currently, I have this:
[image: Currently]

What I want:
[image: Desire]

I somewhat know about the directlabels package and how to avoid clipping. But I cannot find anything about adding arrows/lines that labels and points to each line. I have plots with many more lines that are clustered together, so the arrows would really help.

Here is my code if you want to reproduce this plot. Thanks.

```
library(ggplot2)


year <- 2008:2018

cvd <- rnorm(11, 15, 1)
alz <- rnorm(11, 10, 0.5)
ui <- rnorm(11, 9, .8)
stro <- rnorm(11, 6, 3)

df <- data.frame("Year" = as.factor(rep(year, 4)), "Number of Deaths" = c(cvd, alz, ui, stro), "Cause of Death" = c(
  rep("Cardiovascular Disease", 11),
  rep("Alzheimers Disease", 11),
  rep("Unidentified Cause of Death", 11),
  rep("Stroke", 11)
))

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Year, y=Number.of.Deaths, group=Cause.of.Death, color = Cause.of.Death)) + geom_line() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It wouldn't be a bad idea to include `set.seed()` at the beginning of your script for reproducibility purposes ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look into library(ggrepel).

This is close to what you are looking for:

```html
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(ggrepel)

year <- 2008:2018
cvd <- rnorm(11, 15, 1)
alz <- rnorm(11, 10, 0.5)
ui <- rnorm(11, 10, .5)
stro <- rnorm(11, 6, 3)

df <- data.frame("Year" = rep(year, 4), "Number of Deaths" = c(cvd, alz, ui, stro), "Cause of Death" = c(
  rep("Cardiovascular Disease", 11),
  rep("Alzheimers Disease", 11),
  rep("Unidentified Cause of Death", 11),
  rep("Stroke", 11)
))

#Sorry, I think in terms of data.table.
dt <- data.table(df)

dt2 <- dt[Year==2018]

ggplot(data=dt, aes(x=Year, y=Number.of.Deaths, group=Cause.of.Death, color = Cause.of.Death)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text_repel(data=dt2,
                  aes(x=Year,y=Number.of.Deaths,label=Cause.of.Death),
                  direction = "y",
                  nudge_x = .5,
                  hjust=0,
                  size=3,
                  segment.size = .2,
                  segment.colour = "black")+
  #xlim(c(2008,2020))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=2008:2018,limits = c(2008,2020))+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]